# Basic conditionals not working after update

Tags: conditionals, date, advanced-conditionals

I just did some really really basic updates to my site, and now I'm having some extremely weird behavior. Take this conditional for example:

```
{if '{expiration_date format="%U"}' <= '{current_time format="%U"}'}
```

Despite outputting both these variables between comment-statements and actually seeing that expiration_date is higher then current_time (i.e. `1358865518 / 1358336648`) the result is still being output.

Now in another template I'm using MX Calculcator in a conditional to check for certain entry-counts (`{exp:mx_calc expression="mod(({count}-10),19)"}`), which was working just dandy til 5 minutes ago, and now always resolves....

Has anyone ever had this before? The only changes I've done are to templates...

Comment: What do you mean with "basic updates"?

Comment: Templates, static files (css, js, images), one or two unrelated modules were updated (Exp-resso Store and Stash).

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of EE, the last version or so had a problem with conditionals.

Comment: gah! dammit! I'm on 2.5.1. ok thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so apparently this is a pre `2.5.3` bug. Updating to `2.5.5` resolved this.

Comment: Good to know...my installations are on 2.5.3, but I was worried about problems happening!! (I'll still want to get the sites upgraded from 2.5.3, though. I know they had two dot-rev updates released in December 2012.)